# Display level 3 submenus on level 1 hover - Magento 2 menu

Tags: magento2, menu, magento2.2.3

When a user hovers over a parent top level menu item, i want to display it's direct submenu, as all as any other submenus of that submenu.

Please see the design that i'm trying to achieve below.

[image: 3 levels of menu]

I don't think it's possible to achieve this with css alone, so I think i need to overwrite the menu.js file. So i've followed the below tutorial to achieve this.

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/extending-magento-2-default-js-components/comment-page-1/#comment-438131

I just don't know where to go from here. Can anyone help me?

Also, the workflow to make changes to this file is horrific so any tips on improving that would be welcomed. Do I really need to deploy static files everytime I make a change, regardless of whether I have caching turn on or not?